# How to choose the method of circuit analysis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics, batteries

I was just doing some revision, and I was wondering how to figure out which method to use for solving a given circuit? I tried using mesh analysis on the attached circuit but I got it completely wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis ? The main reason for mistakes in mesh analysis is messing up signs. As Wikipedia says, "It is usual practice to have all the mesh currents loop in the same direction. This helps prevent errors when writing out the equations".

Comment: All proverbial analytic methods are just special cases of the general approach, which is writing all the equations you know about the circuit and then solving the algebra. My advice is do that general method rather than wonder which special-case method to use.

Comment: Yeah I made sure all the mesh current loops were going the same way, i'm not sure what is wrong. Also I will try a more general method.